# Espresso - Click by text in List view

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to click on a text in a list view using Espresso. I know they have [this guide](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples#Matching_data_using_onData_and_a_custom_ViewMatcher), but I can't see how to make this work by looking for text.  This is what I have tried

> ```
> Espresso.onData(Matchers.allOf(Matchers.is(Matchers.instanceOf(ListView.class)), Matchers.hasToString(Matchers.startsWith("ASDF")))).perform(ViewActions.click());
> ```

As expected, this didn't work. The error said no view in hierarchy. Does anyone know how to select a String? (`"ASDF"` in this case) Thanks in advance.

### Update due to @haffax

I received error:

> com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.

### Second error

With this code

> ```
> onData(hasToString(startsWith("ASDF"))).inAdapterView(withContentDescription("MapList")).perform(click());
> ```

I get this error

> com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with content description: is "MapList"'.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No data found matching: asString(a string starting with "ASDF")

---

### Solution

> onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withContentDescription("desc")).atPosition(x).perform(click())

Comment: The interesting bit of this exception is further below in the stack trace. There should be a "Caused by:" part in the whole stack trace. That describes what really went wrong. Please share the complete stack trace for analysis.

Comment: @haffax, Check that. That string is for sure there.

Comment: @haffax, however, there is a Linear layout first.

Comment: This is getting more complicated. So, you actualy don't have access to the adapted type, is this correct?

Comment: @haffax The adapter has a linear layout in the list items. the text is within that.

Comment: Do you know the type of what myListView.getAdapter().getItem(0) returns?

Comment: There is a difference between the View of an item at position 0 and the adapted data at the same position.If your Adapter is an ArrayAdapter<String>, then the adapted data is of type String, but the View representing that item can be e.g. a TextView. For onData(myMatcher) myMatcher does not match the TextView, but it matches the String.

Comment: If you don't have access to the backing data type, then you need to go over the position of that item in the ListView, using onData(anything()).inAdapterView(...).atPosition(x).perform(click()) to click on the x'th item in the list.

Comment: @haffax `myListView.getAdapter().getItem(0)` would return a Relative layout, with 4 linear layouts contained in it

Comment: @haffax, would this work?

Comment: I assume anything() is a custom matcher you created. Care to share it with us as well?

Comment: I have been running into issues using a custom list view class that extends AdapterView. Been seeing this error.  (java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is, that you try to match the list view itself with the `instanceOf(ListView.class)` as argument for `onData()`. `onData()` requires a data matcher that matches the adapted data of the `ListView`, not the `ListView` itself, and also not the `View` that `Adapter.getView()` returns, but the actual data.

If you have something like this in your production code:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
ArrayAdapter<MyDataClass> adapter = getAdapterFromSomewhere();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then the Matcher argument of `Espresso.onData()` should match the desired instance of `MyDataClass`.
So, something like this should work:

```
onData(hasToString(startsWith("ASDF"))).perform(click());
```

(You can use another Matcher using a method of `org.hamcrest.Matchers`)

In case you have multiple adapter views in your activity, you can call `ViewMatchers.inAdapterView()` with a view matcher that specifies the AdapterView like this:

```
onData(hasToString(startsWith("ASDF")))
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.myListView))
    .perform(click());
```

Comment: Answer extended to include solution for multiple AdapterViews in hierarchy.

Comment: I am getting the same error, but with less `**MATCHES**`

Comment: The two that match, seem to be the same though. The only difference I can see is one `is=focused=false`

Comment: Well, you'll have to sort the matching out yourself. Seems weird to have so many different list views with the same id. Can't you give your list views different IDs? Or is this because the are used in ListFragments? Other ways to further distinguish: Assign a tag to the view and use the hasTag() matcher or use isDescendantOfA() to distinguish via hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah I think it is odd too. i didn't write the app, I just test it. But yes, you're right, I can't give them different id's cause they are in ListFragments. I will look in to adding a tag.

Comment: If I look in the uiautomatorviewer, I only see one ListView. I don't get how its finding two??

Comment: Alright, so I have given one list a content description. How could i click by text within content description?

Comment: Be aware that if you have e.g. nav drawer with list view, it can be a second adapter view! so as it was already said, `inAdapterView()` must be used in that case to differentiate between them

Answer (score 3):

If adapter have custom model class for example `Item`:

```
public static Matcher<Object> withItemValue(final String value) {
        return new BoundedMatcher<Object, Item>(Item.class) {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("has value " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(Item item) {
                return item.getName().toUpperCase().equals(String.valueOf(value));
            }
        };
    }
```

Then call following:

```
onData(withItemValue("DRINK1")).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.menu_item_grid)).perform(click());
```

Comment: this works for me on one screen, but on another screen, Espresso seems to scroll to that item, but the item is not clicked even if perform(click()) is called (tested this with breakpoints)....this is very weird

Answer (score 0):

```
onData(hasEntry(equalTo(ListViewActivity.ROW_TEXT),is("List item: 25")))
        .onChildView(withId(R.id.rowTextView)).perform(click());
```

This works best for me with row text data..