# Espresso: how to click on StickyListHeadersListView item inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have ViewPager with N tabs with StickyListHeadersListView inside each of them. I'd like to perform click on one of the list item. How could I do that?
thanks!

PS: I'm interested in Espresso test code only

Comment: are you writing your own adapter?

Comment: What kind of elements / objects do your lists have? 
Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965839/espresso-click-by-text-in-list-view which should give you an idea about clicking on list items. 
Also, swiping across tabs in the viewpager is pretty straightforward, there's a viewaction defined for that. 
You need to provide more information (some code that you've tried) if you really need help. Why would I spend my time guessing what you're actually trying to achieve when your research/trial&error efforts are minimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution myself.
The main issue - StickyListHeadersListView is a wrapper around ListView, it doesn't extend ListView. So we can't work with adapter directly, but we can do this:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(allOf(
  isAssignableFrom(AdapterView.class), 
  isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.list)), 
  isDisplayed()))
.atPosition(1).perform(click());
```

Answer (score -2):

Put this code in method where you are adding your view in viewPager:-

```
for(int i=0;i<arrPagerItems.size();i++)
{
    View viewPager;
    ListView listView;

    viewPager = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_pager,null);

    listView = (ListView) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listChat.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View listView,int position,long arg3) {

            //do your task

            }
    });

    viewPagerAdapter.addView(viewPager, i);
    viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

With Listview, you put into fragment.view pager have fragment. after you can check click listitem in fragment.
Custom :https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator